# facebooktemplate causes "'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'user_id'" when run in a facebook app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, razor

Been following the tutorial for the new facebook mvc template from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=269921

However even with the basic app template I'm unable to get it to run as it just flags the following error:

### Server Error in '/' Application.

```
'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'user_id'
```

With the following stack trace:
Source Error:

```
 An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 



[RuntimeBinderException: 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'user_id']
   CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object ) +152
   System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1(CallSite site, T0 arg0) +1519
   Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Facebook.FacebookAuthenticationModule.<Init>b__5(Object sender, EventArgs e) +1595
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +466
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +576
```

I am completely at a loss here as I can find no "user_id" reference in the sdk, or the default app template, no idea where it is even coming from (unless fb has updated)

Tried existing apps, new apps and even a blank app using the NuGet package, all end in the same error, any ideas
(and before you ask, yes I have followed the tutorial to the letter)